# Ошибка с функцией ANY

Tags: sql, postgresql

База данных PostgreSQL
Имеется такая вот функция

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION loop_over_rows() RETURNS BOOLEAN AS $$
DECLARE rec RECORD;
BEGIN
    FOR rec IN SELECT duplicates FROM public.tmp LOOP
        UPDATE public.table SET field_id = MIN(rec) WHERE field_id = ANY (rec);
    END LOOP;
    RETURN TRUE;
END;
$$ LANGUAGE PLPGSQL;
```

Мы из таблицы tmp берем поочередно массив чисел (bigint [])
В другой таблице есть поле, которое может содержать значения из этого взятого массива. И если нашлась такая строка, то этому полю мы присваиваем минимальное значение из этого массива.

При выполнение выдает следующую ошибку

```
ERROR: ОШИБКА:  для операторов ANY/ALL (с массивом) требуется массив справа
```

Таблица tmp состоит из одного столбца bigint[] (duplicates - название столбца)
К примеру

```
{1001, 1004}
{1122, 1234, 1102}
и т.д
```

Таблица table состоит из двух столбцов id и field_id

```
1 1001
2 1003
3 1004
4 1102
```

Я хочу взять массив из первой таблицы, к примеру {1001, 1004}.
Найти во второй таблице все строки, в которых field_id равна хотя бы какому то из значений во взятом массиве. И заменить в этой найденной строке field_id на минимальное значение из взятого массива.
То, что я описал - я делаю в своей функции. Но как я понял, делаю что-то не так.

Comment: Что то мне подсказывает, что вы свой предыдущий вопрос задали не корректно, в итоге получили не тот ответ, который вам нужен. Необходимо точно описать в вопросе, где у вас тут массив, а где одиночное значение. Ваш предыдущий вопрос читался как поиск одиночного значения в массиве, вот вам и предложили ANY. А у меня ощущение что вы хотите найти одиночные значения, встречающиеся в массиве ... можно конечно просто переставить поля местами, что бы массив был в ANY, но это не эффективно

Comment: @Mike
Нет, к примеру у меня таблица состоит из двух полей : id, field1
И в ней следующие данные:
(1 1001)
(2 1003)
(3 1004)

В моем массиве числа {1001, 1004} 
Соответственно я хочу в своей таблице найти все строки, в которых field1 равна чему то из этого массива. И в случае есть найду - заменю на минимальное из этого массива

Comment: Но ваш предыдущий вопрос звучал как есть таблица со строками (1, {1001 1004}), (2, {1004, 1005}) т.е. в таблице поля содержащие массив и вы хотите найти строки в массивах которых, встречается одиночное число 1004. И вот на тот вопрос вам там и ответили

Comment: Кстати, а что такое min(rec) ? rec это возвращаемая запись, а не одно поле и даже если бы это было поле, функцию min к нему невозможно было бы применить. Так что предлагаю данный вопрос расписать более подробно, что где находится, что на что надо заменить.

Comment: @Mike
Добавил больше информации в вопрос

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Если я правильно понял, где у вас тут массив, а где что, то цикл вам вообще не нужен, а весь запрос сведется к:

```
UPDATE public.table
   SET field_id = min_val
  FROM (
      select (select min(x) from unnest(duplicates) as x) min_val,
             unnest(duplicates) val
        from public.tmp
  ) q
 WHERE field_id = val
```

Основной в запросе является функция `unnest()`, которая разбирает массив на отдельные записи.

Comment: Спасибо, да. Я не знал про такую функцию. Думал, что без циклов тут никак. Буду знать)